# Installing Homestead on Windows 10 without Virtualization

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualization, homestead

I'm trying to install Homestead on my laptop but the CPU doesn't support virtualization. When i try to vagrant up it stucks on the ssh veritification and gives a timeout error. Could you please give some suggestions on booting it, please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you install virtual box 32 bits ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution is enabling Hyper-V as explained [here](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-enable-configure-and-use-hyper-v-on-windows-10). Hope it works out for you.

Comment: dude i told you that i don't have Hyper-V. Please read before answering